# Pseudocode or algorithm for finding 'n' sets that have the most unique values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, pseudocode

Say I have many sets of integers. The number of integers can vary between each set. I am looking for 'n' number of sets that has the most unique integers between them. If n=4, then I'm looking for 4 sets out of all of the available sets that has the greatest possible number of unique integers between them (so not counting duplicates).

Comment: So the cardinality of the union of the selected sets should be as large as possible? I'm asking because it's not entirely clear what you mean by "greatest possible number of unique integers between them"

Comment: As I understood he wants to merge the n sets then remove the duplicates and that new array obtained needs to have the largest possible size

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm not sure what is meant by cardinality of the union but Programmer describes it properly. In the case of n=4 I need to find the 4 sets that when merged has the greatest size (assuming default set behavior such that all duplicates are ignored).

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is NP-hard if *n* is not fixed

Answer (score 1):

If total number of sets = N is not too large:
a brute force approach would be the following one:
consider each of the (N choose n) possible combinations of sets and evaluate the number of unique integers they form by "merging and removing duplicates in a vector then checking size" till you get the maximum after all evaluations.
starting from this you can make more and more efficient algorithms by using dynamic programming or eliminating many of the (N choose n) for example after finding some MAX=K then if total number of ints in this specific n set is less than K you do not evaluate it...etc
that's a rough draft to get you started

Comment: n choose k is generally a recursive approach? Any resources to refresh my mind on this? I recall doing something like this some time ago... If n=3 then I would choose the first set, the second set, and iterate thru the rest for the 3rd and then store the max? Then unchoose the 2nd and choose the next one and then iterate through the rest again for the 3rd? If any have a greater max, store them. Otherwise unchoose the 2nd and keep going down the list until all have been chosen then move the first selection down and repeat?

Comment: The recursive way is one way of doing it which is if I understood what you said well should be about right
Another way would be to hard code it with nested loops
I would go for the recursive way since it makes the code more lenient, if you have an issue with it try to start a specific and precise question about that =)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged C++.  If I understand you correctly, the following does what you described.  Since std::set stores unique values anyway, the C++ code solution becomes straightforward.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::set<int> IntSet;
typedef std::vector<IntSet> IntSetV;

// sort the sets in ascending order, by size
bool SortBySetSize(const IntSet& s1, const IntSet& s2)
{ return s1.size() > s2.size(); }

void OutputResults(const IntSet& s)
{  std::cout << "There are " << s.size() << " unique integers in this set" << std::endl; }

void InputData(IntSet& s)
{
   // routine to input data into s
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   size_t nSets;
   cout << "Enter number of sets: ";
   cin >> nSets;

   IntSetV VSets(nSets);
   //...  input to fill in the sets in the vector
   for_each(VSets.begin(), VSets.end(), InputData);

   // sort the sets by size
   std::sort(VSets.begin(), VSets.end(), SortBySetSize);

   // VSets now contains the N largest set of unique integers.
   for_each(VSets.begin(), VSets.end(), OutputResults);
}
```

If you need to remember the original inputted values, maybe store

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>, IntSet> PairSet;
std::vector<PairSet> IntSetV;
```

The first value in the pair is the original vector, the second is the set that represents the numbers in the vector.  Then the general code solution can be used, with the requisite changes added.

Comment: But choosing the largest N might not be the optimal solution, so this doesn't work. For example `N=2` and `VSets = [{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2},{3,4}]`. It's better to choose `{1,2,3}` and `{3,4}`

Comment: `I am looking for 'n' number of sets that has the most unique integers between them`. I coded as to what I understood what this meant. You have N sets (stored in a vector) and since sets store unique numbers anyway, all you need is the size() call. Or am I missing something?

Comment: "unique integers between them"

I could have worded it better but I'm not sure how to do that. Basically Niklas comment above explains it. While the first 2 sets are the largest, they both contain the exact same numbers 1, 2, 3. So they have 3 unique integers total. But if you choose the last 2 sets then you have 4 unique integers: 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Then dump all the numbers in a "super set" and that is your answer.  No?

Comment: In some sense yes but I need to keep track of the max size and the contributing sets.

Comment: I think you can leverage most of the code I wrote to keep track of the maximum size, original values, the new sets, and the max set.  Issue is that it uses more memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is the NP-hard [maximum coverage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem). The greedy algorithm (grow the union by the set with the most new elements) achieves a solution that is within a factor 1 - 1/e (~ 63%) of optimum. Even though maximum  coverage is NP-hard, [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) often can find optimal solutions for "natural" instances (as opposed to those resulting from an intelligently designed NP-hardness reduction). The main challenge would be integrating a solver; in particular, the solver implements all of the relevant algorithms. The most straightforward formulation for maximum coverage is this.

```
maximize sum_{elements e} x_e
subject to
for all elements e, x_e - sum_{input sets S such that e in S} y_S <= 0
sum_{input sets S} y_S <= n
for all elements e, 0 <= x_e <= 1
for all input sets S, y_S in {0, 1}
```

The meaning of variable `x_e` is whether `x_e` appears in the union. The meaning of `y_S` is that it's `1` if `S` appears in the union, and `0` otherwise.